# %>% and group_by() and mutate() in R

Tags: r

I am newbie to R so my question may be unclear and the mistake may be very basic.

There is a existing R code works fine previously but today suddenly it doesn't work anymore.

The problem is that each cell in the mutated Beginning_Position col become the total of all original Beginning_Position instead of the sum of each Ticker group. I checked the file format, data itself, etc, and everything looks fine to me. How come it worked okay but suddenly can't work anymore?

```
library(xlsx)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data1 = data1 %>% 
  group_by(Ticker) %>% 
  mutate(Beginning_Position = sum(Beginning_Position))
```

Thanks and your advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Do you want `mutate` or `summarise`? The difference is that the former gives one result per row and the latter one result per group; 2) You are assigning the result back to `data1`. If you restart by reading in the data from the XL file, does the error persist?

Comment: Are you running the code once or multiple times? I see you assigned the ouput to `data1`, so each time you run this it would make `Beginning_Position` bigger. The first time, it would make each row show the sum of all the Beginning_Positions for that Ticker. But the 2nd time it would get bigger by being the sum of those sums. And then the sums of the sums of the sums and so on. I often use one variable for the raw data as loaded, and then one or more subsequent variables to hold versions after further manipulation steps.

Comment: You can always ensure that you're making changes by creating a new object. Instead of `data1 = data1...` Use something like `data2 = data1...`

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your reply. All of them are helpful for me. The code is extraction so it may be confusing. Next time, i try to make my question more easier to follow and to the point.  The problem has resolved after I updated my R version....